# Return MySQL Query as Array for Specific Table Row Clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I've been working on this for about 3 days and still cannot figure out how to do this even with all my searches.

Here's what I've already accomplished:

I have a table in `index.php` that fetches data from a MySQL Database. When a user clicks on any given row in the table, I want the `eventDetail.php` page to open.

Here's what I haven't figured out yet:

THEN I need `eventDetail.php` to run a MySQL query that fetches the data for the table row which was clicked on the previous `index.php` page and store it in an array so I can use the data on the `eventDetail.php` page where needed.

Here is the code on the `index.php` page that opens my `eventDetail.php` page:

`index.php`

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function onClickRow() {

    $('.clickDetail').click(function(){
    var str=$(this).attr("value"); /* Find out which button is clicked, stores 
    its value in variable 'str'*/

    $(window.location = 'eventDetail.php').load('eventDetail.php?str='); /* To 
    collect data from database */
    })
    })
    </script>
```

Here's what I have so far in `eventDetail.php` but not even sure if I've started correctly:

`eventDetail.php`

```
    <?php

        $db_host = '127.0.0.1'; // Server Name
        $db_user = 'root'; // Username
        $db_pass = 'password'; // Password
        $db_name = 'mydb'; // Database Name

        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
        if (!$conn) {
            die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

    $str=$_GET['str']; // collect the row id

    $queryRow = ("SELECT id, eventName, description FROM mytable WHERE 
    id=:id");
```

I need the `id, eventName, description` from the row which was clicked on the previous page to be returned to an array so I can actually use that data on this page.

Comment: You're mixing different mysql apis for one thing. `WHERE 
    id=:id` is PDO syntax (placeholder method) and could be the reason why it's not working for you.

Comment: You haven't passed your string value to the URL: `$(window.location = 'eventDetail.php').load('eventDetail.php?str=' + str);` Then in your query you need to plug the string for the `id` value in the `WHERE` clause: `WHERE id='" . $str . "'"`

Comment: @BobRodes Thank you this made my SQL statement work. Now I have this to create the array:

        `$items = array();
        
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $queryRow);
        while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
            $items[$row['id']] = $row['eventName'];
        }

echo $result;`

But it throws the following error: Recoverable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Not sure why you're upset that I didn't respond instantly

Comment: For `$items[$row['id']] = $row['eventName'];` try `$items[] = $row;`.

Comment: As for FunkFortyNiner, I wouldn't worry about it. Check out his profile. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out thanks to @BobRodes.

This is the script you need in `index.php`:

```
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function onClickRow() {

            $('.clickDetail').click(function(){

            var str=$(this).attr('value'); // Find out which button is clicked, stores its value in variable 'str'

            $(window.location = 'eventDetail.php?str='+str).load('eventDetail.php?str='+'/'+str); // To collect data from database
            })
            })
            </script>
```

And this is the php code you need in `eventDetail.php`:

```
  <?php

$db_host = '127.0.0.1'; // Server Name
$db_user = 'root'; // Username
$db_pass = 'password'; // Password
$db_name = 'mydb'; // Database Name

$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$conn) {
    die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

   $str = $_GET['str']; // collect the row id

   $queryRow = ("SELECT id, eventName, description FROM mytable WHERE id='$str'"); // SQL Statement

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $queryRow); // Execute SQL Query
  $items = array(); // Create an array and store in a variable called $items
  // Statement below fetches the row that was clicked and stores the data in the array $items
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $items[] = $row;
  }
  }

  // Statement below separates each item in the array and converts it to a string and stores in variable named $item
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item['id'];
    echo $item['eventName'];
    echo $item['description'];
  }
   mysqli_close($conn);
   ?>
```

This will open `eventDetail.php` and return the table row in the database that was clicked in the url. You can then edit the code in the rest of the page to return the data from that row as you like on the page.